# Magento - Show payment type discounts on home

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using now a promotion that gives 10% discount if the user pays with bank transfer. It's working as expected, but what i want to do is show this discount on another page (like Home, or product page), not just on checkout.

Like this

```
Price: R$ 500,00 
Credit Card: 10x 50,00
Bank Transfer: R$ 450,00 (10%)
```

Someone can give me a hint? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show a static data or you want dynamic data on every page? In both cases you can create a static block and put information there.

If you want to show static data than you can directly put the content in the static block and call that static block in the position which is common to the site on all pages like header, footer etc.

If you want to put dynamic data than create a template get the information of rule programmatically and call that template on the static block.